# Is there a place to upload open source code for others to utilize?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, client-object-model

I am very new to SharePoint just began working in it within the last month. I have been creating Taxonomies within the Managed Meta Data for a company website, and I have run into a lot of issues with importing MMD. Unfortunately the web-UI does not provide some of the functionality that I was looking for.

For example, importing bulk synonyms, and getting feedback on which terms or term sets were not being imported from a csv file. Furthermore I have realized there is no open source CSOM code that would accomplish these tasks.

So I wrote my own that allows users to import a csv file (same format as for the web UI) and provides much more functionality (error logs, bulk importing of custom properties). I wanted to share this with the community in the event anyone else was in my situation.

Is there a website dedicated to open source client and server side code for the community?

Thank you

Comment: Codeplex, or github maybe. But there is no central register of this type of apps

Answer (score 1):

Typically people will have accounts on something like GitHub, pastebin, jsfiddle, etc to share things like this.

The sharepoint.stackexchange site isn't necessarily the place for it. The way around promoting your code is to ask a specific question, then answer it with your code and point to your github repo.

Answer (score 0):

There are many places but most popular are below.

You can upload to the following free places.

- [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/)
- [TechNet Gallery - resources for IT professionals](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/)